# Animate SVG patternTransform with GSAP

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have this in my svg:

```
<rect fill="url(#texture)" width="100%" height="100%" />
<defs>
    <pattern id="texture" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="scale(0.5)" width="300" height="300">
        <image id="texture-image" xlink:href="texture.png" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

and I would like to use the library [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) to animate the **patternTransform** property of 'texture', for instance *from* **scale(0.5)** *to* **scale(0.8)**.
But since it's not a normal numeric or color property, which are easily handled by the the library, I have trouble doing it.
I tried in a different way with [rAF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) but it doesn't work either actually:

```
var svgTexture = document.getElementById('texture'),
    scaleValue, scaleLimit, increaseBy;

function animate(value, limit, step) {
    scaleValue = value;
    scaleLimit = limit;
    increaseBy = step;
    animateSvgTexture();
}

function animateSvgTexture() {
    var val = scaleValue - increaseBy;
    if ( val < scaleLimit ) {
      return false;
    }
    svgTexture.setAttribute('patternTransform', 'scale('+ val +')');
    requestAnimationFrame(animateSvgTexture);
}

/**
 * Provides requestAnimationFrame in a cross browser way.
 * @author paulirish / http://paulirish.com/
 */
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
        return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function( /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element ) {
                window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 );
        };
    })();
}
```

and then when I want to start the animation I call this for instance:

```
animate(0.3, 0.2, 0.01);
```

Anyway I really hope someone can shed some light on how to use GSAP to reach this result, using something like this syntax:

```
TweenLite.to("#texture", 1, { 
    patternTransform: 'scale(0.8)', 
    ease: Power2.easeInOut 
});
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it out.
In case anybody needs it, here's how to do it:

```
var svgTexture = document.getElementById('texture'),
    anim = { 'scale' : 0.5 }; // 0.5 is the initial default value

TweenLite.to(anim, 2, { 
    scale: 0.3, 
    onUpdate: function() {
        svgTexture.setAttribute('patternTransform', 'scale('+ anim.scale +')') 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Kuus, it's not animated for me.
Is there a way to move pattern to left ?